# XPS15 fails to suspends after upgrade to ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, 17.10

Since migrating to ubuntu 17.10 I have had some issues with suspending my system (Dell XPS15 with nvidia / intel dual graphic card)

When I press the power button briefly or call systemctl suspend, I can see that the system tries to go in suspended mode but it comes back on after a few seconds. Extracts from the syslog below

```
[ 2968.230422] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 2968.230485] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2968.439210] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: WARN: xHC CMD_RUN timeout
[ 2968.439222] suspend_common(): xhci_pci_suspend+0x0/0xd0 returns -110
[ 2968.439227] pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -110
[ 2968.439246] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x130 returns -110
[ 2968.439249] PM: Device 0000:3e:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
[ 2968.939220] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: Ignoring mailbox command error (-110) in icm_suspend
[ 2968.939329] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[ 2968.939464] PM: resume of devices complete after 0.129 msecs
[ 2989.664896] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 2989.664899] OOM killer enabled.
[ 2989.664900] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

And according to lspci

```
3e:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge] (rev ff)
```

Running the stock Ubuntu kernel. No special tweak

Anybody facing the same issue with a way to resolve this ?

Comment: What is the version of the laptop? There are several XPS 15 in the market (mine for example is 9550)

Comment: I've come back again here, as my laptop sometimes doesn't suspend, and i see similar errors as the ones reported on this question (my Dell is XPS 15 9550). Restarting the system fixes the problem for some time. When it starts happening the suspend seems to always fail.

Comment: XPS 9550 as well

Comment: I manage the fix the same issue. See the anwser in https://askubuntu.com/a/1018210/130032

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The system won't shutdown after upgrade to 17.10. I shifted to earlier stable version of kernel from grub at startup, and now everything works fine. I am currently using `4.10.0-37-generic` and was facing problems on `4.13.0-16-generic`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same issue on 17.04, also with an XPS 15. Disabling the USB device 'fixes' it - or at least allows you to suspend.

You can unbind the USB device with the command (using answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111112/unload-kernel-module-for-only-a-specific-device-preferrably-from-code-in-anothe?rq=1) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/541854/disable-specific-pci-device-at-boot))

`echo "0000:3e:00.0" | sudo tee --append /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind`

Comment: Not the same issue then as this trick did not work for me.

What version of the dell firmware do you have right now?

Comment: Hmm weird. I'm getting the exact same log when suspend fails, except for the `OOM killer enabled.` line.  According to `dmidecode -s bios-version` I have BIOS version 1.2.19.

Comment: Right. Seem the issue on my side was introduced by upgrade to bios v 1.4.0. Reverting to 1.3.0 fixed things for now. Will file a bug report and see what comes of it

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisParis on my machine with updated Ubuntu 17.10 and BIOS 1.5.1 the problem is not happening any more. Have you tried the 1.5.1 BIOS? https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=TWKFC

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a Dell XPS 15 9550 (also with both Nvidia and Intel graphics) running Ubuntu 17.10. I get the same lines in syslog:

```
[23886.943531] suspend_common(): xhci_pci_suspend+0x0/0xd0 returns -110
[23886.943536] pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -110
[23886.943542] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x130 returns -110
[23886.943546] PM: Device 0000:3e:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
[23887.443502] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: Ignoring mailbox command error (-110) in icm_suspend
[23887.443583] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
```

I don't understand why (found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358966)), but I can resolve the issue by uninstalling the `intel-microcode` package with `apt` (or you can go to the "Software & Updates" application, navigate to the "Additional Drivers" tab, and select "Do not use this device"):

[image: Software & Updates]

When I remove `intel-microcode` and reboot, the problem seems to go away, and I can suspend like normal.

EDIT: BTW I am on the most recent BIOS version 1.6.1.

EDIT2: From some recent updates (I believe) it seems as though selecting "Do not use the device" is no longer an option for microcode. I am now on BIOS 1.6.1 (after Dell cancelled 1.6.1 and then re released it later), and the suspend issue seems to still be around... :(

Comment: I've downgraded from 1.6.1 to 1.5.1. Looks like Bios 1.6.1 has been discontinued by Dell, and I suspect it made my laptop work much slower.

Comment: Scratch my last comment. New Bios 1.6.1 (Dell has opened a new one!), seems to work fine on my Dell XPS 15 9550

Comment: See my edit above. I am also on the new 1.6.1, but the issue seems to still be there for me...not sure what I have done differently from you @morhook. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dunno! :( Do you have all the updates on? Are you using wayland or X11? (X11 on my case) @daniel-hathcock

Comment: Ah that might be the issue! I’m on Wayland. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had similar issues on my Ubuntu 17.10 and upgrading BIOS to latest has fixed problems (tested mostly 1.5.1 and a little bit 1.6.1).