# Ubuntu 17.10 refuses to shutdown in Dell XPS 15 9560

Tags: dell, shutdown, 17.10, xps

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 dual boot with Windows10 on my Dell XPS 15-9560 laptop.

I followed the instructions listed here: [Ubuntu linux on Dell XPS 15 (9560)](https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560))

After installation, I'm unable to shut down the system in Ubuntu. The computer displays this error message:

[image]

And refuses to shutdown.

Comment: Just to confirm - based on those instructions you are using the binary nVidia driver and not the default nouveau one?

Comment: Hi Oliver, I am using the default nouveau one. Thanks

Comment: @OliverOberdorf: Following the instruction, I installed the binary nVidia driver. The problem persists with, see the screen grab for details: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ZrOkhmlr9V7osd-lmfcFhzrVBVR-fYi/view?usp=sharing). Thanks

Comment: hmm - do you have any network mounts in your fstab?  It seems like that can cause issues too.  See comment #72 in this thread

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405/comments/72

Comment: full  bug for reference is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405

Comment: You might doublecheck nouveau is gone, comment #75 in that thread has your exact model of Dell and had the same shutdown error until they switched to the nvidia driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 17.10 on Dell XPS 15 9560. The problem seems to be with the grub options and video driver. I manage to fix the issue by following instructions on the post https://connorkuehl.github.io/dell-inspiron-7559-linux-guide/index.html. In my case I did install the version nvidia-390 instead of nvidia-367

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the nouveau one, you might find this thread useful.  The original post is a startup error, but the 2nd answer mentions your exact shutdown error and also solved it with the nVidia binary drivers.

[NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:305]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)

You may need to blacklist or remove the nouveau drivers.  You can do that with the appropriate portion from this post, adding it in /etc/modprobe.d/

[Install Nvidia driver instead of nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau)

For example, I have:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-384_hybrid.conf:blacklist nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-384_hybrid.conf:blacklist lbm-nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-384_hybrid.conf:alias nouveau off
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-384_hybrid.conf:alias lbm-nouveau off
```